# Нужно сравнить два LIst<Integer> поэлементно?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Есть `list1 - (10,1)` и `list2 - (1,10)` есть метод `Integer.compare(int one, int two)`. Списки визуально равны, но результат выдает `-1`. Как можно реализовать логику, чтобы результат был `0`, т.е равенство. Не могу сообразить. Если можно общий вариант для разных размеров листов. Ну на крайний случай хотя бы для этого примера.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону метода `containsAll();`

Comment: попробуйте  сортировать и потом сравнить

Comment: Спасибо все решил через совет сеньора помидора)

Answer (score 3):

Так как у вас листы содержат неупорядоченные данные, то вам нужно сначала отсортировать их, а потом сравнивать.

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));
// list1.containsAll(list2)
```